# Move one file or folder from one location to another by passing path as a argument in PHP working with Dropbox API?

Tags: php, dropbox-api

I have this piece of code.

```
$str1 = $test."\\".$actualfilename;
$str2 = $finalPath."\\".$folder."\\".$subfolder;
$source = mb_convert_encoding($str1, "UTF-8");
   echo "<br/>". $source;
 $dest = mb_convert_encoding($str2, "UTF-8");
 echo "<br/>" .$dest;
$client->move($source,$dest);
```

Want to move file but getting this error:

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message ''fromPath': bad path: must start with "/": "C:\\Dropbox\\Salesforce Documents\\Opportunities\\UR-000001\\123432.pdf.txt"' in D:\xampp\htdocs\dropboxapi\vendor\dropbox\dropbox-sdk\lib\Dropbox\Path.php:169
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message indicates that the `fromPath` should start with `"/"`, but yours starts with `"C:\\"`.

When performing file operations on the Dropbox API like this, the remote file paths need to be relative paths in the Dropbox folder. That is, something like `"/folder/file.txt"`.

You're instead passing the local file path. To fix this, use the relative paths of the files in the account instead.